# Arduino Micro Serial.print string not returning a string

Tags: arduino

So I am trying to use the serial to communicate to the arduino. I want it to print "Firing the motor" when I type 1. I have the program here:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); //Connect to the serial monitor console
}

void loop() {
    while (Serial.available() == 0); //Wait until Serial is available

    //Read val
    int val = Serial.read() - '0'; //Val that represents input
    Serial.print(val);

    delay(1000);
    if (val == 1) {
      Serial.print('Firing the motor.');
    } else {
      Serial.print('Please press 1 to fire the motor.');
    }

    delay(4000);
}
```

The problem is that instead of returning "Firing the motor." or "Please press 1 to fire the motor." all the console simply returns 0. I have also tried removing the - '0'

I have also tried saying:

```
if (val == 1) {
  Serial.print("Firing the motor.");
} else {
  Serial.print("Please press 1 to fire the motor.");
}
```

and adding the "" instead of ''

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

did you set the monitor at the same baud rate ?? (9600) 
 i mean here 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlVyR.jpg)

Comment: Yes, it is set at 9600